# Liquibase Maven can't read changeLogFile

Tags: java, xml, maven, plugins, liquibase

According to my 
[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLeEZ.png)
I got an error

> liquibase.exception.SetupException: file:/src/main/liquibase/changes/000-initial-schema.xml does not exist

My pom.xml plugin is configured like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>src/main/liquibase/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My liquibase.properties files are:

> driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
>   url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/versioned 
>   username= 
>   password= 
>   changeLogFile=src/main/liquibase/master.xml

My master.xml is

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">
<includeAll path="src/main/liquibase/changes" />
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Why Liquibase can't find that file ? Even if i change that file name to: 000-initial-schemaTEST.xml the error is:

> liquibase.exception.SetupException: file:/src/main/liquibase/changes/000-initial-schemaTEST.xml does not exist

I'm putting also that file (it was generated from database by generateChangeLog goal)

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">
<changeSet author="arek (generated)" id="1489753245544-1">
    <createTable tableName="user">
        <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="INT">
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="arek (generated)" id="1489753245544-2">
    <addUniqueConstraint columnNames="id" constraintName="id_UNIQUE" tableName="user"/>
</changeSet>
```

To comparation when master.xml file is:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

<include file="src/main/liquibase/changes/001-add-user-address.xml" />
<!--<includeAll path="src/main/liquibase/changes" />-->
</databaseChangeLog>
```

It works

Answer (score 5):

Solution is to update **master.xml**:

```
<includeAll path="changes" relativeToChangelogFile="false" />
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason of that was maven Liquibase version.

That error happens only in versions:

- 3.5.3
- 3.5.2

In 3.5.1 and below it works.

Maybe someone knows why it not works in 3.5.2 and 3.5.3 and how it should be configured in these versions ?

Comment: And version 3.6.2.

Comment: And version 3.6.3

Answer (score 3):

liquibase find the files to include but do not load them correctly.

In this example, liquibase find the file include.xml when listing the content of your folder but don't manage to load it.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.3:update (default-cli) on project testLiquibase: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.SetupException: file:/src/main/resources/include/include.xml does not exist -> [Help 1]
```

This issue is track: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2980

Answer (score 0):

In my case solution was to add to db-changelog-master.xml for each "include" tag, statement: relativeToChangelogFile="true" like this:

```
<include file="e6ebb/ddl/61-someChanges.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
```